# jquery show div, stay some seconds and then close with fade animation

Tags: jquery, animation, slide

I want to show a result message div after grid is updated.

I want that message div will slide down with fade animation, then stay for 5 seconds and then auto close with slide up animation

my code looks like this. But only slide up animation works.

```
$("#gridResult").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideDown(500, function () {
    $("#gridResult").addClass('in');
});

$("#gridResult").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
    $("#gridResult").removeClass('in');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
// you need to hide the grid for slide down to work
$("#gridResult").hide().slideDown(500, function () {
    // delay 5 seconds AFTER animation has completed
    $(this).addClass('in').delay(5000).fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('in');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gridResult">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer placerat dui at lacinia ultricies. Ut at massa nec metus pellentesque sodales. Maecenas sit amet tristique nisl. Donec rutrum sapien sed mauris lacinia, nec consequat enim tincidunt. Donec nisl ante, bibendum eget ligula eget, suscipit volutpat leo. Proin scelerisque ultrices urna eget fermentum. Duis rutrum velit quis orci lobortis lobortis. Phasellus hendrerit mi vitae urna pulvinar pretium.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use delay() from jQuery, see https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Sample from doc:

```
$( "#foo" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this on js:

```
$("#gridResult").slideDown(500, function () {
        $("#gridResult").addClass('in');
    }).delay(5000).slideUp(500, function () {
        $("#gridResult").removeClass('in');
    });
```

css:
on first state

```
 #gridResult{
        display: none;
    }
```